# Exporting Table Data to Google Spreadsheet via XPath

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, row

I´m trying to export table data to Google Spreadsheet by using the importxml command and XPath but it doesn´t work. A parser error appears, which says that there´s an error while parsing the formula.

I want to get the mobile PIs from this page: http://ausweisung.ivw-online.de/index.php?i=1121&a=a9170

I tried a command like this: `=IMPORTXML("http://ausweisung.ivw-online.de/index.php?i=1121&a=a9170"; "//*[@id="ibody"]//div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[5]")`

*As mentioned in the comments below, I also want to perform the request more dynamic. I want to search for a specific string and then jump to a column of my choice.*

Comment: Well, the delimiter for arguments is `,`, not `;` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: You have to use `;` instead of `,` , otherwise you´ll receive an error that the formula cannot be parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a user from the Google product forums I got the right formula to solve my request correctly.

`=arrayformula( value( regexreplace( query( importHTML("http://ausweisung.ivw-online.de/index.php?i=112&mz_szm=201408"; "table"; 3) & ""; "select Col5 where Col3 = 'GLAMOUR (Smartphone-Apps)'  "; 0 ); "[^\d]"; "" ) ) )`

This request is looking for a specific string in a specified table, and grabs the data from the fifth column in this row.

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula error because you use double quotes (`"`) inside other double quotes. You have to use single quotes inside a string that is delimited by double quotes.

```
=IMPORTXML("http://ausweisung.ivw-online.de/index.php?i=1121&a=a9170", "//*[@id='ibody']//div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[5]")
```

The result is still `#N/A`, presumably because your path expression does not match anything.

**EDIT**

> I´m looking for the right xpath command to get (in this case) just the data '11.824.563'.

The correct expression to retrieve this value would be:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://ausweisung.ivw-online.de/index.php?i=1121&a=a9170", "//div[@class='statistik']/div[@class='uebersicht']/table/tr[3]/td[2]")
```

But unfortunately, IMPORTXML is so buggy and unreliable that this still yields "#N/A" as a result. This seems to have worked in older versions of Google Spreadsheets:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/yWPaNDK0Kpg/3UIIeDA0SAIJ

Comment: @deesch You are welcome. Is your problem solved? Then, please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If you are still in search for the correct path expression, explain what you're trying to find.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I still don´t understand why the result is #N/A. The xpath expression seems to lead to the proper content in the correct column.

Comment: I want to extract the Mobile PIs from the page.

Comment: @deesch This: `<tr><td>mobile PIs:</td><td class="werte" nowrap="nowrap">11.824.563</td></tr>`?

Comment: I´m looking for the right xpath command to get (in this case) just the data '11.824.563'.

Comment: to be more precise: I want to create a dynamic request, which searches for a specific string (e.g. 'Deutsch') and grabs the data from column x. (I want to avoid grabbing the wrong data, if the the host of the page adds a line to the table.)

This would be the correct way to perform a static request:

`=index(importHTML("http://ausweisung.ivw-online.de/index.php?i=1121&a=a9170"; "table"; 5); 4; 4 )`